# Adding socket timeout to http4 client using RequestConfig in Java DSL in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

So, I have a `route` which essentially looks like this-

```
from("direct:send_success")
        .to("http4://localhost:8089/mock/success?httpClient.socketTimeout=1000");
```

Using this way, I'm able to apply socket timeout of 1 sec successfully. I am using `ProducerTemplate` to invoke this route. This is all fine. But when I change the route to-

```
from("direct:send_success")
    .to("http4://localhost:8089/mock/success");
```

And route invocation to-

```
ProducerTemplate pt = ctx.createProducerTemplate();
Exchange ex = pt.send("direct:send_success", exOb -> {
    HttpComponent httpComp = exOb.getContext().getComponent("http4", HttpComponent.class);
    exOb.getContext().getComponent("http4", HttpComponent.class).setHttpClientConfigurer(httpClientBuilder -> {
            HttpClientBuilder
                .create()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfigWithTimeout(1000))
                .build();
        });
});
```

And the method `requestConfigWithTimeout()` as-

```
private static RequestConfig requestConfigWithTimeout(int timeoutInMilliseconds) {
    return RequestConfig.copy(RequestConfig.DEFAULT)
            .setSocketTimeout(timeoutInMilliseconds)
            .build();
}
```

The timeout settings are not applied. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the http component **after** the Camel route has been created and started. Then the route was created with the http4 component which has not had its configured changed with that *extra code you do*.

So configure the http4 component earlier and not when you send the message.

Comment: Ok. I was able to do the same for SOAP endpoint  using cxf's `ClientPolicy` in request header so I thought there would be a workaround here as well. Anyways, thanks for the help.